# How to bind ReactiveCommand with IObservable?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, system.reactive, reactiveui

I have a command (`ReactiveCommand`) and I want to execute this command when a user selects an item in a list.

A list exposes an observable `IObservable<object>` so each time there is a new event sent to this observable I want to execute my command.

I came with this but it seems quite complicated for what it does.

```
source.ElementSelected
    .Cast<Item>()
    .SelectMany(ViewModel.ShowDetailsCommand.Execute)
    .Subscribe();
```

I wonder if there is a better way to do it? Is there something like `BindCommand` that exists for commands and controls?

Comment: https://docs.reactiveui.net/en/user-guide/commands/binding-commands.html scroll to the bottom "this.BindCommand(
    this.ViewModel,
    x => x.MyCommand,
    x => x.myControl,
    nameof(myControl.SomeEvent));"  is that what you're thinking?

Comment: @ShaneNeuville That does not work because I don't have an event.

Comment: aw ok you have an "event" but not an Event  :-) . Reading more carefully I see what you mean. In that case not sure :-/ usually I'll have what you have but using WhenAnyObservable or similar. Most of the samples in RxUI also use similar syntax as what you have with chaining an observable into an Execute. Though invokeCommand could also clean up what you have a little bit. https://docs.reactiveui.net/en/user-guide/commands/invoking-commands.html. Otherwise would probably just need to make your own extension method.

Comment: @ShaneNeuville Thanks for the tip with `InvokeCommand` that cleans it up and make it more understandable.

Comment: Cool!! And just in case you didn't see it in the docs I just want to make sure to point out "InvokeCommand respects the command's executability. That is, if the command's CanExecute method returns false, InvokeCommand will not execute the command when the source observable ticks."  so behavior wise it's not a complete one to one with what you have up above.

Comment: @ShaneNeuville In this case it does not matter but it is good it works like that. It will be handy in future, thanks again! Feel free to put the `InvokeCommand` as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I'll have what you have but using WhenAnyObservable or similar. Most of the samples in RxUI also use similar syntax with chaining an observable into an Execute.

Though InvokeCommand is one way to simplify down a little bit.

https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/invoking-commands

Otherwise would probably just need to make your own extension method.

Also I just want to make sure to point out

> InvokeCommand respects the command's executability. That is, if the
>   command's CanExecute method returns false, InvokeCommand will not
>   execute the command when the source observable ticks.

Comment: You should update the link, as it appears to be broken. Try https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/invoking-commands instead